# ASP.NET Core asp-validation-for error message not displaying at input level

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a form with the standard asp.net validation Tag Helpers for field validation:

```
<form id="myForm" asp-area="myArea" asp-controller="myController" asp-action="myAction" data-ajax="true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <!-- other html excluded for brevity -->
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm customer-po" asp-for="@Model.PurchaseOrder" value="@Model.PurchaseOrder" placeholder="enter customer po number" maxlength="50" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.PurchaseOrder" class="text-danger"></span>
</form>
```

Because this particular field is only required when very specific conditions are met, it gets validated server side like so:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("PurchaseOrder", $"PO is required to Approve order"); 
return Error();
```

I get the validation error message at the summary level however I do not get the error message at the field level.  Upon inspecting the markup, the `<span>` element for the error message is there however it has no inner html.

I have also tried using the following to no avail:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.PurchaseOrder, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you share when you add model error to Model State?I add error to ModelState when return the view which contains the form,and it can show error at the field level.

Comment: I add the error server side in the second snippet above: `ModelState.AddModelError("PurchaseOrder", $"PO is required to Approve order"); `

Comment: Yes，I mean when you add it,such as click a button,or return the view?